# How to handle objects created within the method under test

Tags: spring, unit-testing, junit, mockito

I have the following model classes:

```
@Data
public class Address {
    private String street;
    private int number;
}
```

```
@Data
public class Person {
    private String name;
    private Address address;
}
```

and the following services:

```
@Service
public class MyService {
  private final OtherService otherService;

  public MyService(OtherService otherService) {
    this.otherService = otherService;
  }

  public void create() {
    Person myPerson = new Person();
    myPerson.setName("John");
    otherService.synchronize(myPerson);
    myPerson.getAddress().setNumber(12);
  }
}
```

```
@Service
public class OtherService {
    public void synchronize(Person person) {
        Address address = new Address();
        address.setStreet("sample street");
        address.setNumber(123);
        person.setAddress(address);
    }
}
```

I want to write a unit test for MyService. This is the not working version of the test:

```
@ExtendWith(SpringExtension.class)
class MyServiceTest {
    @Mock OtherService otherService;

    @InjectMocks MyService myService;

    @Test
    void test_create() {
        // GIVEN
        doNothing().when(otherService).synchronize(any(Person.class));

        // WHEN
        myService.create();

        // THEN
        verify(otherService).synchronize(any());
    }
}
```

This fails because the `myPerson` object is created within the method being tested and therefore I get a `NullPointerException` when running the test. How could I deal with this issue? should I capture the value passed to the otherService?

Comment: It fails because `getAddress()` in `create` method returns null

Comment: Yes exactly. but this is what I want to deal with. The real service won't throw the exception because the real otherService will set the address field.

Comment: So, if you want simple verify, that `synchronize()` method was called,  the `Address` still must be not null to avoid throwing NPE. You can use `doAnswer(invocation -> { Person person = invocation.getArgument(0); person.setAddress(new Address()); return null;}).when(otherService).synchronize(any(Person.class));`

Comment: Is this what you are looking for?

Comment: yes thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

There's a little complexity but it's not bad.  Replace your doNothing call with something like this:

```
Mockito.doAnswer(
    new Answer<Void>() {
       public Void answer(InvocationOnMock invocation) throws Exception {
            Person arg = invocation.getArgument(0);
            arg.setAddress(new Address());
            return;
      }
    }).when(otherService).synchronize(any(Person.class));
```